# how to import data from database.db file to room database using Room.databaseBuilder() .createFromFile?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, persistence

I have an android application that imports the data from **database.db**.
I use `Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "db").createFromFile(path)` but it does not give any data.

My code is :

```
public static synchronized AppDatabase getDb(Context context){

    if (db==null){
        if (new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath()+"/db.db").exists()) {
            db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "db")
                    .createFromFile(new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/db.db")).build();
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/db.db", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
    return db ;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not `createFromAsset`?

Comment: MikeT it do the the same work, just the folder change

Comment: According to the https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate your solution should works fine if app has permissions to access the file with path  "/db.db" and the scheme of db in file same with room's scheme. Do you get any error when try tp create db ?